# compilation error while building war file

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am getting this error when i run `mvn clean install` command manually;

```
[INFO] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/dao/daoImpl/SsoDaoImpl.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[9,23] package org.apache.http does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[10,23] package org.apache.http does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[11,30] package org.apache.http.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[12,30] package org.apache.http.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[13,38] package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[14,38] package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[15,30] package org.apache.http.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[16,35] package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[17,31] package org.apache.http.message does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[18,32] package org.apache.http.protocol does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[19,28] package org.apache.http.util does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[136,53] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpResponse
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[33,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpClient
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[33,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DefaultHttpClient
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[34,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpGet
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[34,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpGet
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[38,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpResponse
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[41,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ClientProtocolException
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[58,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpClient
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[58,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DefaultHttpClient
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[59,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpPost
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[59,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpPost
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[63,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpResponse
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[65,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ClientProtocolException
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[79,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpClient
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[79,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DefaultHttpClient
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[81,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpPost
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[81,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpPost
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[85,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StringEntity
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[85,57] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StringEntity
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[86,57] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BasicHeader
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[86,69] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable HTTP
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[89,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpResponse
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[93,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ClientProtocolException
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[109,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpClient
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[109,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DefaultHttpClient
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[111,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpPost
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[111,41] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpPost
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[115,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StringEntity
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[115,57] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StringEntity
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[116,57] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BasicHeader
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[116,69] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable HTTP
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[119,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpResponse
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[124,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ClientProtocolException
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[140,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpEntity
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[157,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable EntityUtils
  location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[INFO] 46 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.589 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-29T00:35:37-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/63M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project opt: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[9,23] package org.apache.http does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[10,23] package org.apache.http does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[11,30] package org.apache.http.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[12,30] package org.apache.http.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[13,38] package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[14,38] package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[15,30] package org.apache.http.entity does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[16,35] package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[17,31] package org.apache.http.message does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[18,32] package org.apache.http.protocol does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[19,28] package org.apache.http.util does not exist
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[136,53] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpResponse
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[33,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpClient
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[33,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DefaultHttpClient
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[34,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpGet
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[34,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpGet
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[38,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpResponse
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[41,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ClientProtocolException
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[58,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpClient
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[58,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DefaultHttpClient
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[59,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpPost
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[59,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpPost
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[63,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpResponse
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[65,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ClientProtocolException
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[79,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpClient
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[79,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DefaultHttpClient
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[81,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpPost
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[81,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpPost
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[85,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StringEntity
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[85,57] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StringEntity
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[86,57] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BasicHeader
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[86,69] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable HTTP
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[89,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpResponse
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[93,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ClientProtocolException
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[109,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpClient
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[109,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DefaultHttpClient
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[111,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpPost
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[111,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpPost
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[115,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StringEntity
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[115,57] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class StringEntity
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[116,57] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BasicHeader
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[116,69] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable HTTP
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[119,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpResponse
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[124,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ClientProtocolException
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[140,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpEntity
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] /home/bean/opt/src/main/java/com/trident/service/Salesforce/HttpService.java:[157,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable EntityUtils
[ERROR] location: class com.trident.service.Salesforce.HttpService
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The fun part is, i have jenkins job which pulls the latest code and run the same `mvn clean install` and it works.

Why i am not able to do it manually?. And also i tried by creating another jenkins job with the same build steps. For that also its giving same error.

here is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.trident</groupId>
  <artifactId>opt</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <!-- <properties>
    <org.springframework-version>4.3.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final</org.hibernate.version>
  </properties> -->



 <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>6.0.5</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                     <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                     <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                     <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
              </dependency>


        <!-- SLF4J/Logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

            <!-- JSON dependencies -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ldap/spring-ldap-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>opt</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>opt</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you miss the http-Client from apache as dependency.

Add it to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you. That worked. But how come jenkins job is not giving any compilation error? Do you have any idea?

Comment: maybe it is in the classpath of  the jdk which is used for compiling. But it is only a wild guess